# How to integrate Pentaho reporting in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, pentaho

I have a requirement to generate report in Pentaho, and display in asp.net pages.
If any one know about implementation of Pentaho with ASP.Net please Replay....

Comment: I am try to integrate pentaho report to my website. It was working in Crome using iframe, but not working in IE and firefox. I think it cross domain security.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho runs using the Tomcat, which runs in a Java environment.

You have to create a frame and call a web service that will return the report(or you can use AJAX).
see this [example](http://bdietzblog.blogspot.in/2008/12/pentaho-bi-server-using-action.html)

Comment: I am try to integrate pentaho report to my website. It was working in Crome using iframe, but not working in IE and firefox. I think it cross domain security.